# Are the dimensions of the top panel LCD screen on a Canon 50D same as the 7D or 5DM2?

Tags: canon, equipment-protection, lcd, canon-50d

I'm trying to buy a LCD top panel screen protector for my 50D and I could only find protectors for the top LCD screen for the 5D Mark 2 and 7D.

So will they fit the LCD top LCD on my 50D? Is it the same size?

Here's the one I'm looking at on ebay. [7D Top+Back Screen Protector](http://www.ebay.ie/itm/3X-Top-Back-Screen-2in1-Protector-Film-Canon-Eos-7D-/290667566112?pt=UK_Photography_Screen_Protectors&hash=item43ad231420)

Answer (score 3):

No they are not the same size as the 50D.

I determined this by referencing and measuring the two images [here](http://a.img-dpreview.com/reviews/CanonEOS7D/Images/InhandTd.jpg)(7d) and [here](http://a.img-dpreview.com/reviews/CanonEOS50D/images/InhandTd.jpg)(50d). It looks like the 7d has a bit wider LCD screen by about 15% or so.

I would suggest just buying a standard sheet of LCD protector and cutting it to the desired size. If you have trouble finding that you can just buy a set of ones designed for tablet PCs or similar.

Comment: Thanks so much! Yes I knew I could do the DIY version using a generic LCD protector, but I'm lazy and wanted a pre-cut one. According to your judgement from the pictures, the 7D should be large in both length and width to the 50D, right? Then I'll just get it and trim a bit off instead of cutting my own from scratch. Thanks again.

Comment: I didn't measure the height, but I would guess it is either taller or the same, so I believe you should be fine ordering it and trimming as needed.  As a note - I've had a 40D for 5 years and my top screen has never scratched at all without any protection. I also am quite hard on my equipment. I don't think a protector is necessary.